# Make a request to the current server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource, puma

I have a rails application that includes some ActiveResource services. I try to run a server with this application and make a request from one service to another. Let's say I have an action in service1_controller.rb:

```
def action1
  Service2::Object1.find(10)
end
```

I get a TimeoutError, and I can understand why: the "basic" server knows to run only one thread. So I tried Puma server in order to have more than one thread enabled, but I still get the same error.

Can you figure out why?

Please let me know if the scenario is unclear and if some more information is missing, because I found it very difficult to explain the problem.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but what do think about starting two rails servers in different ports and make requests from one server to another?

Comment: @RodrigoAssis I think you understood well. I tried this solution and used to work like that, but now I need 3-4 servers and it's getting higher, so I wondered if I can have another solution and puma server seemed like the best one for me - but I still get the same error.